# PPP connection between PalmOS and Ubuntu (over ttyUSB0?) without crashy "visor" kernel module

Tags: ubuntu, usb, tty, palm, ppp

I have a Palm Treo 680 which I'd like to use as a media remote, using [Palm MPC](http://palm-mpc.sourceforge.net/). Almost the exact instructions on that page used to work perfectly for establishing a PPP connection over the USB cable; I think I last tried it in Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty). In Karmic, I find that `/dev/ttyUSB{0,1}` are not present by default, and when I `modprobe visor` to get them, the Palm immediately crashes and reboots, as seen in [Ubuntu bug 522753](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/522753) (it reboots again as long as the module is still loaded and USB is still connected). The `usbserial` module has the same result.

From reading that bug and elsewhere, it appears that the `visor` module is abandoned, and `jpilot` and friends use some other approach to talk to PalmOS over USB these days, which might not even involve a `ttyUSB` device. My question is, therefore:

**How do I create a PPP connection between PalmOS and Karmic without crashing the Palm?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a default Karmic 9.10 setup, it is not `visor`/`usbserial` module crashing your Palm, but the buggy modem-manager. Following [this launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/+bug/421673), all you need is to remove `modem-manager` package (and probably reboot).

As there is AFAIK no other way to communicate with your Palm other than through `ttyUSB*`, and because everyone report that their Palm syncs successfully, PPP connection should work too (if you won't do weird things with the tty like modem-manager does)

Comment: Thanks! Removed modem-manager, rebooted and everything works. :-)